# What characters can kill most (if not all) of Timmie's pigeons? Which characters can do it more effectively?

Tags: genshin-impact

I was wondering which characters in Genshin Impact can kill most, if not all of Timmie's pigeons, and most importantly, which characters can do it more effectively.

Comment: I would imagine Aloy, as her trait prevents them being startled when you approach

Comment: Is there an achievement or something upon killing then all at once? Or is it just personal hate against these flying b... pigeons?

Comment: @ChrᴉzremembersMonica Mainly hate against Timmie.

Comment: @DavidYell As soon as you kill any "animal who produce Fowl, Raw Meat, or Chilled Meat" any other animal around **will** attempt fleeing. It is exactly like how Sayu passive works too: if two crystal flies are nearby, getting one will make the other one flee.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you ask Mihoyo, [they probably will answer you "Venti"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jm6tEjL_A-8).

[image]

More seriously.
You would have two factors to consider:

- how comfortable the process is - characters that don't require you to get too close, get in a specific position or aim a lot should get a better score.
- number of characters involved - the less the better. I guess EI skill could help a lot but having multiple characters required should award less points.
- style points, the flashier the process is, the better.

An ideal option for an attack should therefore be easy to use, have a big enough AOE in order to reduce the risk of missing and enough range to avoid scaring the bird by getting too close. This means that ranged AOE attacks or attacks that come out in front of the player are preferred to AOE attacks that are centered around the character.

| Character | Aloy? (*) | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Albedo** | yes | Albedo really doesn't have much to give. His best options is using his burst after getting close enough. You will probably miss some birds. |
| **Aloy** |  | Her main advantage is being able to get very close due to her passive. She is also technically a free character if you played when she was given out. That said, her skills lack the AOE you would want for the process to be as simple as it can get |
| **Amber** | no | Her only option is her burst, which would need quite accurate aiming. Better options exist even considering free-only characters. |
| **Arataki Itto** | yes | Skip, his best option is Ushi. You would miss most of the time and getting close enough also probably requires Aloy. |
| **Barbara** | yes | Skip, lacks any AOE options. Her burst probably would cure the pigeons instead. |
| **Beidou** | yes | The counter probably COULD be fast enough to get all the pigeons, but you need Aloy for positioning yourself in the middle. |
| **Bennett** | yes | Even if you manage to use his burst... it probably comes out too slowly. It also requires Aloy basically. |
| **Chongyun** | yes | See: Bennet. |
| **Diluc** | no | Dawn. Diluc's burst doesn't need much effort to charge, has decent range and area coverage. Also gets bonus style points. |
| **Diona** | no | Cats are known for catching birds, but where is the fun if you kill all the toys at the same time? If you really want to try, probably your best bet is trying to aim her burst in the middle of the group |
| **Eula** | yes | Her elemental skill probably is up to the job, the elemental burst may be too slow. But there are better options. Also, usual problem with range and requiring Aloy to be easy enough. |
| **Fischl** | yes | Skip. Maybe her burst can be used, but that is far from easy and efficient. |
| **Ganyu** | no | Contrary to what the ads wants you to believe, her charged shot can be aimed so that the AOE hits all the birds. That said, expect to miss often allowing some to escape. |
| **Gorou** | yes | He has to use his burst to even get some AOE effect and even then he would probably requires Aloy support too since the attack is centered on the character thus needing you to be in the middle of the pigeon group for max effect. Skip. There is a good chance Gorou Tails and Sayu Sonic would get mad if you hurt poor little birds anyway. |
| **Hu Tao** | yes | Has AOE, but compared to Diluc has the range disadvantage that like always can be offset by Aloy. Gains bonus style point for performing her Hilichurl dance in front of Timmie afterward. |
| **Jean** | yes | Burst seem the only option since trying to use the pull effect of her skill will probably end up with some fugitives. Usual Aloy problem. |
| **Kaedehara Kazuha** | yes | As usual, if you have Aloy both his skill and his burst are perfect. But you probably skipped his banner because "5* Sucrose", right? |
| **Kaeya** | yes | Why would you try to use a bridge to kill pigeons? |
| **Kamisato Ayaka** | no | If done right, her burst can probably be quite flashy and effective. But it will require practice. |
| **Kamisato Ayato** | yes | Similar to Ayaka, but she has the advantage of a frontal AOE burst compared to one centered on the player.That said, the Kamisato Art: Suiyuu range is probably big enough to avoid the usual Aloy requirement. |
| **Keqing** | no | If you manage to throw her sword, teleport in the air and plunge just right, you can get all the pigeons and a Rainbow V score... But would this really count as "efficient" and "easy"? |
| **Klee** | - | Fishes are found in the lake, not on the bridge. Open your map and teleport to Starfell. |
| **Kujou Sara** | no | The trick is to first use her skill, then purposelessly miss the pigeons so that the totem spawns in the middle of the group. If done correctly the effect is basically a 4* version of Ganyu snowflake arrow. |
| **Lisa** | yes | Burst required. And that means Aloy. Can get better if raining. |
| **Mona** | yes | Doesn't have many options but IF you manage to find a way to use the omen skill and then another character for the actual blow... I guess you get bonus EXP point for the completely unneeded overkill, courtesy of Chara. |
| **Ningguang** | yes | Probably not worth the effort when you have better options. |
| **Noelle** | yes | Getting close enough to use her burst followed by a giant sword swipe can be stylish I guess. |
| **Qiqi** | - | ***DON'T***. Qiqi place is in your pot with a finch, not on a bridge. |
| **Raiden Shogun** | yes | Very flashy and stylish at the risk of missing some birds. |
| **Razor** | yes | Most of his skills are quite slow, you have better options. |
| **Rosaria** | yes | You could try to user her burst maybe? Not worth the effort anyway. As usual, requires Aloy. |
| **Sangonomiya Kokomi** | yes | Can manage but I would expect the process to feel quite clunky. That said, she would get bonus style points for her animations. |
| **Sayu** | no | I have seen some trying the bowling ball technique but it doesn't feel very accurate. When it works just right it gets bonus style. |
| **Shenhe** | yes | Can do, especially if paired with Aloy. Can also be pretty stylish if you like the character. |
| **Sucrose** | no | Another character with a large AOE skill and burst that hits a zone in front of the character (instead of around the character like for example Jean) so she has an advantage. Her skill is probably already enough for the task but her burst makes things even easier. |
| **Tartaglia** | yes | Can manage, with Aloy support making thing easier as usual. But you will always live with the weight of the knowledge that it could be ten times better if you could use the Foul Legacy version instead... |
| **Thoma** | yes | Better used to clean the feathers left afterward. |
| **Traveler** | no | Geo version burst can be good paired with Aloy, but the Anemo one oddly takes the place as best option after you learn to line up correctly. Just don't try to use Electro. |
| **Xiangling** | no | The pyronado isn't as good as you would expect as some birds will often manage to escape while the fire blade circles around you. CAN work if you time it right so that you run into the pigeons as the blade is rotating in front of you |
| **Xiao** | no | IF you manage to use his burst, jump high enough and land on the pigeons you can get every single one and be in Mask form at the same time for added style. |
| **Xingqiu** | yes | Skip, doesn't have any real option. |
| **Xinyan** | yes | Better than Xingqiu but still unreliable. |
| **Yae Miko** | yes | Even if you manage to deploy the towers, it would still depend on RNG god. |
| **Yanfei** | no | Burst seems only option, still not good enough compared to other characters. |
| **Yoimiya** | - | Even with her attack speed, not fast enough. A pity. IF she could manage to get every bird with just her normal attack... she would be the winner by far just for sheer style. |
| **Yun Kin** | yes | Same issue as most characters, her AOE is centered on the player and thus benefits from Aloy. |
| **Venti** | no | The advertisement does not lie. His burst is the best option for ease of use. It is also worth noticing that with [proper placement](https://youtu.be/WPNGn3ZhBCI?t=68) Venti burst can keep the pigeons unable to escape while not killing them, giving you more time to get a closer look at their useless attempt to fly away. |
| **Zhongli** | no | What does Morax say when he goes to the Mondstadt KFC branch? **"I will have order"** |

So
Best Free option: Traveler (Anemo)
Best 4* options: Sucrose, Sara
Best 5* options: Venti, Ganyu, Diluc

I will leave you the final choice, but whatever option you take will only take you one step closer on the road to the Abyss. *And your soul will forever be crushed by the pain of remorse the day you will get the alternate version of Pigeons Go AWOL and discover WHY Timmie is always alone watching pigeons... (**)*

---

(*) note: this just means that Aloy is suggested, not required, so no need to point it out if you manage to avoid her. I am just trying to list who benefits from her and who doesn't.
(**) and if you have no heart and that does *not* bother you, perhaps realizing that the game must be tracking how much you bully Timmie (otherwise Teyvat Times could not have included any stat) may perhaps make you reconsider about the consequences of your actions should the devs really get playful...

Comment: Worth noting that now Yelan is released in 2.7, her charged hydro arrow can get all the pigeons in a single hit.

Comment: not what is discussed but FYI, if you kill/chase away Timmie's pigeons during nighttime, then when he spawns during daytime, he just asks why his pigeons haven't shown up yet